# what is the equivalent circuit for a Complementary Split Ring Resonator (CSRR)?

Tags: antenna, high-frequency, resonance, pcb-antenna

Can any one help me find the equivalent circuit and how to calculate the resonant frequency of a CSRR **(not SRR)** like in the one in the figure below?

[image: CSRR]

Here is the S11 parameter of the CSRR obtained by CST studio

[image]

If there is any article about this I will be grateful, if you can link to it in a comment.

Comment: it could be a 10th order RLC transmission line with unequal coupling on 5 dielectric boundaries and mismatched on at least 2 sides and 2 tiny gaps .  conductor and dielectric geometries are converted by coplanar modelling of strips. Do a 3D sensitivity analysis on every tolerance!

Comment: Start reading https://goo.gl/nbBSFl. 1st model a simple design http://digital-library.theiet.org/docserver/fulltext/el/53/8/EL.2017.1090.04.gif.html

Comment: thanks a lot @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 for your response, I have read this article but it's all about simple designs of SRR and CSRR. do you have an idea how to pass from these models (2 rings) to 4 rings as in my case ?

Comment: sorry I have no personal experience in this model, and would opt to follow my own advice if I wanted to learn. trace thickness and dielectric material are critical to results of geometry